# Jade/pug setting MIME type of javascript file to text/html

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Hey I've been trying to use jade/pug to have my node.js backend render my pages in the front end. I need to include some javascript to make some functionality work but I can't seem to get it to load correctly. I get this error:

**"The script from “http://localhost:3000/public/javascript/newCust.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.**

**new Loading failed for the  with source “http://localhost:3000/public/javascript/newCust.js”."**

I have tried setting the content type to javascript and tried moving the directories around to help solve the issue.

```
script(type='text/javascript' src='public/javascript/newCust.js')
```

Comment: This isn't a problem with pug, it has to do with your server configuration.

Comment: This isn't a problem with pug, it has to do with your server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I see you had put your static javascript files in the correct place, i.e in a folder named public.
But, in order to serve all static files : html, css and javascript files, you need to add a built-in middleware function, namely *express.static()*, in your entry point which is usually app.js or index.js file, like so :

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
// you can also use the absolute path, using npm package named path like below :
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

The express.static() function will combine your static javascript file with that public folder. Therefore, in your pug file, you should write as follow :

```
script(type='text/javascript' src='./javascript/newCust.js')
```

***not***

```
script(type='text/javascript' src='./public/javascript/newCust.js')
```

You don't even need to add the MIME type in that script tag, because by default, the script tag will have the correct MIME type of :

```
type='text/javascript'
```

Try with and without adding that MIME type, both should work.

For more detail about using express.static() function, you can read in [Express built-in middleware function : express.static()](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static)